# grading using vba codes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use vba to grade the class here are my codes and information.

3 conditions, if grades are 100 or above, it will show 100+, if it's 50 or above, it will show 50+. Else, it will show below 50. I am trying to create a button in sheet2 so when I press it, the codes will run in sheet1. The range will vary every month so that is why I tried to loop to the last row in column A. I am also showing you a snapshot of the result I am trying to produce. My question is when I run the code, it has an error for else without if. Need a suggestion or advice.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim I As Integer
Dim lr As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To lr
If Cells(I, 1).Value >= 100 Then Cells(I, 2).Value = "100+"
   ElseIf Cells(I, 2).Value >= 50 Then Cells(I, 22).Value = "50+"
      Else: Cells(I, 2).Value = "Below 50"
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written the the `If` statement as in-inline `If` since the code to run is on the same line as the `Then` statement.  To use an `Else` or `ElseIf` you need to format it differently.  Try this:

```
If Cells(I, 1).Value >= 100 Then
    Cells(I, 2).Value = "100+"
ElseIf Cells(I, 2).Value >= 50 Then
    Cells(I, 22).Value = "50+"
Else
    Cells(I, 2).Value = "Below 50"
End If
```

This will solve your first error "*else without if*"

---

Personally, I like using Select Case for this kind of logic.

```
Select Case Cells(I, 1).Value
    Case Is >= 100
        Cells(I, 2).Value = "100+"
    Case Is >= 50
        Cells(I, 22).Value = "50+"
    Case Else
        Cells(I, 2).Value = "Below 50"
End Select
```